# cannot resolve from state ' ' . What configuration did i put wrong?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to go using ui-sref but it's saying `cannot resolve from ''`. What did I do wrong in the route configuration. Everything seems correctly configured from my point of view. But i am getting this error.

**view**

```
 <li><a ui-sref="container.demurrage.index">Container Management</a></li>
```

**Js**

```
angular.module("app.container",
    [
        "ui.router",
        "ui.select",
        "ui.bootstrap",
    ])
    .config([
        "$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider.state("container",
                {
                    url: "/container",
                    template: "<div ui-view></div>",
                    abstract: true
                });
            $stateProvider.state("container.demurrage.index",
                {
                    url: "/demurrage",
                    templateUrl: "/container/demurrageindex",
                    controller: "demurrageIndexController",
                    resolve: {

                    }
                });
    

        }
    ])
```

Comment: Try adding the .html extension in templateUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who has the same issue, I post the solution and it was the naming issue.

If the parent is `container` the children should be `container.{some name}` NOT `container.{name}.{name}`.

```
angular.module("app.container",
    [
        "ui.router",
        "ui.select",
        "ui.bootstrap",
    ])
    .config([
        "$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider.state("container",
                {
                    url: "/container",
                    template: "<div ui-view></div>",
                    abstract: true
                });
            $stateProvider.state("container.demurrageindex",
                {
                    url: "/demurrage",
                    templateUrl: "/container/demurrageindex",
                    controller: "demurrageIndexController",
                    resolve: {

                    }
                });
    

        }
    ])
```